# Do I get charged for attempting to publish messages to disabled endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

Do I get charged for publishing a message to an endpoint, even though this one is saved as not enabled on AWS SNS. Do I need to do a clean up job on my side to make sure that all the endpoints linked to a user are always up to date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you're charged for each authenticated API Request, ontop of additional pricing per Notification etc.

It's currently charged at $0.50 per 1 million API Requests, regardless if it returns a HTTP 200 or not.

> - First 1 million Amazon SNS requests per month are free
> - $0.50 per 1 million Amazon SNS requests thereafter

[Source](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/)

Comment: so, even if the endpoint is disabled, I'm getting charged twice? first for the request and then for the failed notification?

Comment: If we're talking about Device Endpoints, then if the endpoint is disabled, then the notification is never sent, you merely get a REST error stating that you are trying to send to a disabled Endpoint.

So you are only being charged for the API Request

Comment: so, it's probably best to do a clean up job based on inactivity time on my side to get rid of potential disabled device endpoints? (to lower costs)